# Specifying multiple categories in URL (permalink)?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

For example: `http://www.example.com/dell/studio/studio-1558`
where `dell` and `studio` are categories

A few months back I heard from someone that it is not possible. I need to know why? Which part of code prevents it? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some folks asked the same question you did here. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641924/duplicate-sub-category-slugs-in-wordpress) specifically worth reading, if you haven't already. It has [ottopress](http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/) explanation for harmful permalinks.

If you really want to force this, you could write your own permalink (http://domain.com/category/subcategory/post...), then either use htaccess rewrite rule or WP_Rewrite to take them to the link wordpress generated.

This merely satisfies your visual requirement, but it adds server load.

Comment: Sorry, I've down voted this answer as I don't think it actually answers the actual question that was asked, the question was about how to have multiple categories specified in a url. Although it was true in pre WP 3.3 that categories in Permalinks were a bad idea this wasn't actually what the question was about, but as this is fixed in WP 3.3 this also makes this answer inaccurate. The Ottopress post linked above has been updated to show this: http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 1):

You create categories with the correct parent and child/children. The trick is to only select the lowest category, not each one, and WordPress will automatically do that for you, i.e.

```
- Cars
    - Chevrolet
        - Camaro
```

Only check Camaro and WP will make a slug for all the parent items :)